# hadoop single node cluster installation on ubuntu

Tags: hadoop, jvm

I am completely new to Hadoop and I am trying to install Hadoop single node cluster on ubuntu but I am unable to figure out the reason  I am unable to.I am following the tutorials in the following link "http://codesfusion.blogspot.in/2013/10/setup-hadoop-2x-220-on-ubuntu.html?m=1"
Everything went smoothly but when I  give the command "Hadoop version" I get the following error.
"/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop: line 133: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk//bin/java: No such file or directory"
I also opened the same file and searched the entire file but could not find such a line at all .
my .bashrc

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk/
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
###end of paste
```

After that I opened hadoop-env.sh and pasted this ,the java home

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk/
```

Later I re-logged in and checked the hadoop version I am getting this error

```
"/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop: line 133: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk//bin/java: No such file or directory"
```

I also cross verified that particular file but there is no line as such .Anybody kindly help me with this since I am new to this.

Comment: have you tried removing the '/' after jdk?

Comment: which file should i remove it ? i checked  the file /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop  also in line 133 and entire file.. but no such line exists .. where should i edit? please help

Comment: Vishal means you to remove the '/' in the PATH of JAVA_HOME 'export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk/'

Comment: i removed that . now i am getting the same error with the slash removed. "/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop: line 133: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk/bin/java"

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

1. First remove `/` from the end `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk/` in bot `bashrc` and `hadoop-env.sh`
2. navigate to `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk/bin`
   see if it has java folder or not. If its not there then check if u have made the correct soft link.
   You must create a soft link for folder that has java in it so check before this command:

   $ cd /usr/lib/jvm
   $ ln -s java-7-openjdk-amd64 jdk

in above step as u might have seen in the tutorial change as following

```
$ cd /usr/lib/jvm
$ ln -s java-7-openjdk-amd64/ jdk
```

the 7 here is dependent on verion of jdk u have so check that and change accordingly.
I have jdk 6 so i changed for java-6-******

hope it works

Answer (score 0):

This is error due to $JAVA_HOME variable. Change this variable path. you will be free from the error.

go to .bashrc using this command

```
vim ~/.bashrc
```

Change the JAVA_HOME variable

```
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk
 export PATH=PATH:$PATH/bin
```

if you have jdk 8 then replace jdk with java-8-oracle .

```
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
 export PATH=PATH:$PATH/bin
```

restart you terminal and check the java command first, then hadoop command.